# Is throws declaration in feign client useless without defined error decoder?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-feign

I have a feign client like this

```java
@FeignClient(name = "client")
public interface SomeClient {
    @RequestLine("GET /?q={q}")
    void execute(URI baseUrl, @Param("q") String q) throws SomeExceptionInMyCode;
}
```

Looking to this `throws SomeExceptionInMyCode` I'm asking myself when this exception will be thrown. There is no configuration for client defined, no error decoder. Exception looks like this.

```java
public class SomeExceptionInMyCode extends Exception{

    private final int statusCode;
    private final String reason;
    private final String body;

    // getters and setters
}
```

Will there be an automatic attempt to decode HTTP response to this exception in case of failure? Or `throws SomeExceptionInMyCode` is useless and can be removed without any impact.

I searched inside my code and this exception is never created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Will there be an automatic attempt to decode http response to this exception in case of failure?

Nope, it doesn't work like this and the `SomeExceptionMyCode` will not be thrown. The `throws` clause is useless. Even if the endpoint throws this exception from its implementation, it will be wrapped as a cause of `FeignException`.

The correct way to handle feign client exceptions is using [Custom exception handling](https://github.com/OpenFeign/feign/wiki/Custom-error-handling)  implementing `ErrorDecoder`:

```
public class StashErrorDecoder implements ErrorDecoder {

    @Override
    public Exception decode(String methodKey, Response response) {
        if (response.status() >= 400 && response.status() <= 499) {
            // return 4XX exception
        }
        if (response.status() >= 500 && response.status() <= 599) {
            // return 5XX exception
        }
    }
}
```

At this point you can perform the custom exception creation and rethrowing.

An alternative solution is to use Spring-alike `@RestControllerAdvice`:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
public class ExceptionHandler {

    @ExceptionHandler(FeignException.class)
    public String handleFeignStatusException(FeignException e, HttpServletResponse response) {
        // ...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What if the `StashErrorDecoder` throws a checked exception? That is allowed. In this case the `throws` clause in the interface surely helps. This way you can catch and handle the exception thrown by Feign. At least it should work this way.